# How to get single record, filtered by email address, from MailChimp list using API 3.0

Tags: php, json, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Flowing new subscribers from our CRM into MailChimp was easy, **but what I need to do now is to get a single customer record based on only their email address** and fetch their MailChimp ID from the MailChimp API.

The MailChimp API 3.0 documentation has limited examples of using filters for GET calls.  I would think it would be possible to filter the results without retrieving the entire member list, which is what the script is doing now, but I just need that one customer record, not the entire list else I receive the entire JSON string of every member of the list, encode this massive string into an array then I need to iterate through the JSON array to find the record with the matching email address, which seems very inefficient to me.  **I MUST be missing something that's not easily found in the MailChimp API 3.0 docs, no?!**

I am using the PHP library, but it doesn't matter, I really just need to know how to build the API call -- the proper URL (can I append with `?email_address=EMAIL_TO_FILTER` tried it but didn't work) and the JSON array structure.  I have a successful connection with the MailChimp API and built a `mailChimpApiRequest()` method like so:

```
function mailChimpApiRequest($method='POST', $url, $postFields = null){

    $ch  = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $headerArr=array(   'Authorization: '  . $this->apikey);

    if($method!='POST' && !empty($method)) {
      //Not needed: $headerArr[] = 'X-HTTP-Method-Override: ' . $method;
    }

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headerArr );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    if ($postFields) {
        if ($method!=''){    $postFields['method']=$method;}

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postFields));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    }

    $curl_response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $curl_response;
}
```

Can somebody help me figure out what `$url` and `$postFields` array to pass to this `mailChimpApiRequest()` method above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the URL with the MD5 of email address in all lowercase.  Too easy, I missed that in the MailChimp API docs.

Answer (score 0):

You got it Aaron... hopefully this helps others who run into the same issue:
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#read-get_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash

If you can't get to that URL, here's the summary:
use an HTTP `GET` request to the URL `/lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}`
with the `subscriber_hash` being the MD5 hash of the lowercase version of the list member’s email address.